SIMCOM 7600G-Pcie Audio Writing Blocked if Data written when call ends
I just wrote a C# application that waits for a call and picks up the call from the SIMCOM 7600g-Mini pcie module.
I have also connected to the Audio USB Port that is also available when connected, and I am able to read the call audio and write audio to it as well.
However, There seems to be a critical bug where if the call has ended and there was still some bytes being written or if bytes are written after call has ended, the write does get timedout which is expected but once the next call is picked up, the audio reading works but the writing always keeps timing out.
I have tried flushing the buffer but the fix is always replugging in the usb.
It works just fine if no audio is written while the call is ending.
Could this be a hardware fault or am I missing some step that needs to be done?
